# Blue background on click android

Tags: android, jquery, css

I think this is not issues actually but I want to remove this option from some element..

I get blue focus background on click on mobile version. on android.. desktop is okay..

for example this http://prntscr.com/6rxh9x .. when I press this div I get blue bg.. and this is happen only on div and anchor who have some trigger in jquery.. for example this div add class "active" on click.. or maybe this mobile trigger navigation http://prntscr.com/6rxi3y .. also get blue bg.. but its not to much visible because everything is blue :) ..

What I want to do .. is to remove this blue bg from mobile menu trigger.. like its done here on https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile :) if you open thi site on android you will see there is no this blue bg on click on mobile drop triger http://prntscr.com/6rxjgw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

It will helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Check this, it is very well explained !

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground

Comment: this is okay.. but for android developers.. for application I guess.. I need solution for web ( css and html ) .. but thanks.. this is good link for future work on application...